# How to convert cells of DataGridView to int?

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting

I tried

```
int A = DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].value
```

and

```
int A = (int)DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].value
```

or using `Cast` or `Parse` method but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `dont work` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing any of these things.

Your DataGridView should be databound (databind'd) to a DataTable that has a fourth column that is an integer or to a list of objects that has a property that appears in the fourth column of the datagridview, that is an integer:

```
var x = (int)myDataTableThatTheDGVIsBoundTo.Rows[0][3];

var x = myListOfPeopleWhereAgeAppearsAsDGVFourthColumn[0].Age;
```

DataGridView is intended for VIEWing a model of data that is kept elsewhere. If you want data out of the model, you get it from the model, not the view. If you want to know something that is eg what the user selected in the view, or is the current row etc you either retrieve the relevant model rows from the SelectedCell's OwningRow.DataBoundItem or use something like a bindingsource that understand sthe concept of "current row"

To really answer this we need a lot more info about how your data got into your grid in the first place. I get the feeling it's not in a model at all :/

Answer (score 0):

```
   try
   {
        string cellValue = DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        int intCellValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(cellValue);
   }
   catch (FormatException e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
```

The try-catch block is used in case the user somehow inserted a non-integer value in the datagrid.

Comment: what is a Dim ?

Comment: This is VB.NET Code @gadir. It has different syntax of declaring and initializing variables.

Comment: @gadir I am sorry, for some reasons I thought this was in the vb.net topic, as I saw no ; at the end of the rows. Editted the answer.

Comment: @Gabriel Stancu Dont problem thank you for helping me   :)

Comment: @Gabriel Stancu In the cell of data grid user dont enter value ! in the cell just show peice of product that user buy it.. it is integer but when i coding it make exception

Comment: I was just being cautious using the try-catch for data type mismatch. If you could edit the question and at least tell us which row throws the exception and what type of exception, I'd be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will work too.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) //Desired Column
    {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Column1_KeyPress);
        }
    }
}

private void Column1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Found this code sample on another thread.

Comment: Note that this prevents entering non numeric data into a dgv cell, rather than converting existing data in the grid to int

Answer (score 0):

```
 dgwProducts.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value
```

return object.
You can this:

```
int A = Convert.ToInt32(dgwProducts.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```